# how to replace number by string (not every number occurrence)?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

So here is a thing what I want to do:

```
 var string = "/something/12/anything/234/xyz";
 //i want to get this to result out of this ==> "/something/secret/anything/secret/xyz
```

basically replace all numbers with some string "secret".

Comment: @KobyDouek no it will generate sting like "/something/xx/anyhing/xxx/xyz" - which is dependent on number if there is 23 it will be xx and if 123 it will be xxx. what i want is for any number 123 or 23 it should be replaced with secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex `/\d+/g` for replace

```js
var str = "/something/12/anything/234/xyz";

console.log(str.replace(/\d+/g, "secret"));
```